# Is there a way to add token for public api using aws api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm working on a project where we are using AWS API gateway for all the private APIs. Now we are planning to expose a public API for the non-registered users. Since we need token to pass through the AWS gateway, what are the ways that we can have token for the public API? (should be from AWS end, as it doesn't require much changes than the back-end)

OpeID connect isn't ideal solution as it provides, SSO for registered users only

Answer (score 0):

You can add Authorization in the API gateway for your public APIs

In the API gateway console - Under Method Request, click the Edit button next to Authorization and select the type AWS_IAM

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/

If your API needs to be accessed by public clients then you can use OAuth or API Keys. When a client makes a request to the API, they need to include an access token in the Authorization header of the request.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-scopes-api-gateway/
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-aws-lambda-authorizers-with-a-third-party-identity-provider-to-secure-amazon-api-gateway-rest-apis/